# Google Cloud Run gVisor syscall error on node application

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gvisor

My project was running successfully on cloud run and I recently added https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip package to serve my pre gzipped assets and what I noticed is **after deploying to cloud run** the pre gzipped assets are not recognized by the browser (it's working perfectly on localhost)

Also I noticed an error in stackdriver logs.

> Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall
> statx(0xffffff9c,0x3e2292ff7208,0x0,0xfff,0x3e2292ff6df0,0x3e2292ff6f10).
> Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/statx for more
> information.

[image: gVisor Error]

Also noticed the assets served from google cloud run don't have accept-encoding header (When looking into the source code of express-static-gzip package, it uses nodejs file read calls, I assume that file read calls may causing error in gVisor)

## Update:

Getting this "Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall" error even after removing express-static-gzip package too.

Does anyone know about this error?

Comment: Can you package your app into a GitHub package so that we can test this? I think you have two issues - gVisor and HTTP headers.

Comment: Sorry to say that it's an internal project, so i can't able to share source.

On Further checking I found that the "Container Sandbox Limitation" error is not caused by this express-static-gzip package. Getting this error after removing the package too.

@Scarysize may be right, cloud run may not be using the gvisor latest release yet.

Comment: The function statx seems to have been added to GVisor recently: https://github.com/google/gvisor/commit/35719d52c7ac7faa87b610013aedd69ad5d99ecc   You can review the following issues in the Public Issue Tracker and add additional details if needed: https://issuetracker.google.com/138540969  and https://issuetracker.google.com/134694204.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the "statx" system call is implemented in gVisor (since June 19). Maybe Cloud Run isn't using the latest release yet.

Comment: Can we something from our side to fix this or GCloud team have to do it internally? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I don't think you can. You can try and ask your question on the gVisor user mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gvisor-users

Answer (score 0):

This is worth noting while running on Google Cloud Run when you see unsupported syscall error in logs:

Most of the time, failed syscalls don’t  mean your app is failing. Node.js, here, is trying to use statx if it’s available, and falling back to stat system call, which is supported.

Most languages will explicitly print a stack trace while crashing or they will throw an exception when the system call fails. I don’t see that happening here.